# TIMESTAMP field error with LOAD DATA INFILE with Python on Linux

Tags: python, mysql

We are generating test data in CSV format and loading this CSV with Python connector into MySQL. Everything worked fine until we introduced a TIMESTAMP data type in our database.

In our CSV we have millions of rows and some, only some of the rows throw an exception:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2008-03-30 01:12:20' for column 'document_creation_time' at row 17088
```

The date value from the CSV that was passed in via the LOAD DATA INFILE statement in our Python script is:

> 30/03/2008 01:12:20

The SQL expression that we are using in the LOAD DATA INFILE statement to convert the data into TIMESTAMP is:

```
STR_TO_DATE(@backup_time, \'%d/%m/%Y %T\')
```

Interestingly if we execute the same LOAD DATA INFILE statement with LOCAL parameter from MySQL Workbench (and not via Python), it works.

Only when we run it via the Python connector is when we get the error.

We have been trying to fiddle around with character sets but no luck. Both CSV and Database should be in UTF8 set.

We are stuck, any idea to work around this?

UPDATE1: When we load with LOCAL option values change like 01:12:20 becoming 02:00:00

Comment: Can you try using this? -> `STR_TO_DATE(@backup_time, \'%m/%d/%Y %T\')`

Comment: @SujeetSinha: uh, how does that help? OP's original date string is CLEARLY `day/month`. telling them to switch to `month/day` will just kill all the OTHER records

Comment: @MarcB i'm just thinking it might be because of the expected date format in MySQL.. not sure if it resolves the issue and hence didnt post it as an answer..

Comment: op has a string `dd/mm/yyy` in their db, and is converting it on-the-fly in the load command with the str_to_date. there's nothing wrong with either date string, and it converted fine. mysql is being dumb for some reason.

Comment: Is the global timezone on your MySQL server or the per-client timezone for the Python connection set to somewhere in [Western Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_European_Time)? 01:12AM on Sunday 30 March 2008 didn't exist in this timezone because of the change to Daylight Savings Time. This would also explain changing to 02:00AM because that's the next valid time after 01:12AM on this day.

Comment: @MattRaines that is a very good spot! It seems like we need to fix our test data generation script. Also we will need to add the timezone with the data value?

Comment: I'm not sure you can specify on a per-value basis. Apparently MySQL [converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). I think this means you'd need all the import data to be in the same timezone before loading it in.